# FPDF white parts on Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf-generation, fpdf, acrobat

I am having a problem in generating pdf files, I could see that sometimes, some documents generated with fpdf library (version 1.6) show blank parts.

In this part of the document is not displayed were only used blocks of text and horizontal lines I've also used in other documents without problems.

This problem only happens when I open the resulting document in Windows with Adobe Acrobat, whereas when I open it with web browsers or document viewer of Ubuntu this problem is not produced and displayed correctly.

Not show any error, but the problem is that it leaves the incomplete document but if it respects the newline.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the font format is not declared

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
```

It works for me in a similar problem